# Dankbarkeit: how to write such email

Tags: letter

I need your help.

For my help ( work on a research paper) I got " Dankbarkeit" in an envelope. My work was paid such way.

I want to thank my college and I dont know how to write such email: Danke für die Umschlag! or *Vielen Dank für Ihre Dankbarkeit meiner Arbeit*

Please, could you suggest me a template?

Comment: Note: If you write "Danke für <x>", x needs to be in accusative (it's der Umschlag, not die Umschlag in nominative).

Comment: From the context I can guess that "Dankbarkeit" means money. I would never use the term "*Dankbarkeit*" in this context.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain the term "Dankbarkeit" in this context. This use is quite unusual. According to [HalvarF](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44671/halvarf)'s [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70980/danbarkeit-how-to-write-such-email/70982?noredirect=1#comment169926_70982) below my answer, it might be a term that is used in your organization with a special meaning.

Comment: @Bodo: I'd have said that a voucher would be more common as Dankeschön.

Comment: Would you use in English gratuity?

Comment: @FrimHart64 Is "ein Dankeschön" what you meant? That would make much more sense.

Comment: I think it makes a big difference of what actually is in the envelope: whether it is money or another item of value which was somewhat agreed-upon or whether it was sent without being required or expected in some form. Seing you write "paid" it looks not like a 'thanks' but like their fulfilment of a transaction - in which case 'Dankbarkeit' is IMHO the wrong word. I think it would make sense if you could elaborate more on it, and especially if you would write in English what you mean with "Dankbarkeit" (as that doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the term "*Dankbarkeit*" in these contexts.

In your first proposal, "*Umschlag*" is masculine (*der Umschlag*), so it would be

- Danke für den Umschlag.

For your second proposal I suggest

- Vielen Dank für Ihre Wertschätzung meiner Arbeit.
- Vielen Dank, dass Sie meine Arbeit wertschätzen.

---

As [HalvarF](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44671/halvarf) stated in a [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70980/dankbarkeit-how-to-write-such-email/70982?noredirect=1#comment169926_70982), it is not clear if the term "Dankbarkeit" in the question is a simple mistake (my understanding) or if it might have a special meaning (HalvarF's assumption).

Please add more details to the question: How you came to the term "Dankbarkeit", what you actually got, to whom you are writing...

Comment: There might be a reason for calling it "Dankbarkeit" when it is thought that payment or even "Anerkennung" would have compliance or legal consequences. 
If OP insists on calling it Dankbarkeit, even though it's quite unusual to use it that way, then "Vielen Dank für Ihre Dankbarkeit für meine Arbeit." would in fact be a mildly tongue-in-cheek answer.

Comment: Wenn die Frage unklar ist, dann sollte man sie als Schließkandidat mit der vorgefertigten Begründung markieren, statt spekulativ zu antworten. Spekulatives Antworten ermuntert auch andere zum Wettlauf um Upvotes und führt nicht selten dazu, dass die offenen Fragen nie geklärt werden, und die Seite als Schrottplatz zurückbleibt.

Comment: @userunknown Die Ergänzung habe ich nach dem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70980/dankbarkeit-how-to-write-such-email/70982?noredirect=1#comment169926_70982) von HalvarF geschrieben. Erst dadurch kam meine Unsicherheit, ob ich die Intention der Frage richtig verstanden habe. Ursprünglich war meine Antwort nicht spekulativ. Ich habe es umformuliert.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, *Dankbarkeit* doesn't work that way.

However, you got *ein Dankeschön*.

So, e.g. "Vielen Dank für euer Dankeschön!"

- If there was actual money in the envelope, Dankeschön is IMHO the way to go.
- For everything else (Gutschein), you can refer to that directly: "Vielen Dank für den Gutschein".